# AJAX get request and javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, get

Very new to javascript. I'm not quite sure how to explain this so hopefully my example below explains what I have done:

```
  let events = {
    '04-23-2018' : '<a href="http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/11/23/three-script-updates/">Three Script Updates</a>',
    '04-21-2018' : '<a href="http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/11/21/adaptive-thumbnail-pile-effect-with-automatic-grouping/">Adaptive Thumbnail Pile Effect with Automatic Grouping</a>',
    '04-20-2018' : '<a href="http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/11/20/learning-principles-for-improving-your-css/">Learning Principles for Improving Your CSS</a>',
    '04-19-2018' : '<a href="http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/11/19/responsive-css-timeline-with-3d-effect/">Responsive CSS Timeline with 3D Effect</a>'
  };

  $.get( "/api/events").done(function( data ) {
    events["04-26-2018"] = '<a href="http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/04/30/fluid-css3-slideshow-with-parallax-effect/">BING BONG BONG SSSSS</a><a href="http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/04/30/im-creator-giveaway/">IM Creator Giveaway</a>';
  });
```

In the above get request I'm at the stage where I'm debugging. I'm just passing some variables in to test the asynchronous/promissory nature of get requests.

Further down I have the following in my script:

```
let cal = $calendar.calendario({
  onDayClick : function( $el, $contentEl, dateProperties ) {
    if( $contentEl.length > 0 ) {
     showEvents( $contentEl, dateProperties );
    }
  },
  caldata : events,
  displayWeekAbbr : true
});
```

I set caldata to events.

However, caldata only contains the first object - and not the key value pair I have added from within the done function of the get request...

How do I get the data collected to pass back before let cal is declared?? I have tried declaring let cal after declaring the Events["04-26-2018"] key but this let cal is then also needed by other functions from within the script?? So confused and really need some prompts on this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont assign on init, assign caldata after the callback is success as shown below:

```
let cal = $calendar.calendario({
  onDayClick : function( $el, $contentEl, dateProperties ) {
    if( $contentEl.length > 0 ) {
     showEvents( $contentEl, dateProperties );
    }
  },
  displayWeekAbbr : true
});

$.get( "/api/events").done(function( data ) {
    events["04-26-2018"] = '<a href="http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/04/30/fluid-css3-slideshow-with-parallax-effect/">BING BONG BONG SSSSS</a><a href="http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/04/30/im-creator-giveaway/">IM Creator Giveaway</a>';
    cal.caldata = events;
  });
```

Comment: Perfect, worked like a charm. I did try setting async to false - but this is now deprecated in newer jQuery versions.

Comment: Since JS is single threaded, you must always avoid using sync calls and try to handle things async.